# What is an embedding of extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I'm given a definition that I don't understand. I just want to have an understanding of it. It goes as follows.

We have two Field extensions $H$ and $K$ of a field $F$ and a map $v: K \to H$.

They define it as $v$ being an identity on F. I don't understand what that means. Can someone help me out here.

Thanks yall

Comment: It's saying that, for all $a \in F$ we have $v(a) = a$.  All the elements of $F$ are fixed by $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one thing you know for sure about $H$ and $K$ is that they each contain $F$ as a subfield (up to isomorphism).  What they are saying is that $\mu$ fixes $F$, just like the other answers say.  Given some $x \in F \subset K$, its image under $\mu$ is $x \in F \subset H$.

Comment: Most clearest explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It means that $\nu|_F$ is the identity map on $F$. In other words, $\nu(x)=x$ for all $x\in F$.